# Codeigniter - Change layout for specified rows

Tags: codeigniter, html-table

How can I change the layout of specified rows (not all rows) with the HTML Table Class in CodeIgniter? I tried it with the template array, but this effects the entire table respectively all rows.

```
$tmpl = array (
    'table_open'          => '<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">',
    'heading_row_start'   => '<tr>',
    'heading_row_end'     => '</tr>',
    'heading_cell_start'  => '<th>',
    'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',
    'row_start'           => '<tr>',
    'row_end'             => '</tr>',
    'cell_start'          => '<td>',
    'cell_end'            => '</td>',
    'row_alt_start'       => '<tr>',
    'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
    'cell_alt_start'      => '<td>',
    'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',
    'table_close'         => '</table>'
);
$this->table->set_template($tmpl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you, but there's no way to change the layout for specific rows with Codeigniter's [HTML Table class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html). Although the template is customizable,  it isn't customizable down to specific rows or cells, it's more useful for just cranking out a quick `<table>` from an array and is not a complete solution to HTML tables.

Possible solutions without knowing your specific requirements:

1. Wrap each cell in another element by prepping the input array beforehand (if you just need a `.highlighted` class or something), which would produce output like this:

   ```
   <tr>
     <td><div class="highlight">Data 1</div></td>
     <td><div class="highlight">Data 2</div></td>
     <!-- etc. -->
   </tr>
   ```
2. Don't use the Table class at all, but build it the old-fashioned way with HTML, loops and conditionals, which will give you complete control over the layout. **(recommended)**

Comment: This is disappointing. Nevertheless, many thanks for your help. I will try the old-fashioned way with HTML.